# Is that answer "technically" ok?

Tags: discussion, answers

This [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/10407/5741) to the question [Why DAESH does not attack or even threaten to attack Israel?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10394/why-daesh-does-not-attack-or-even-threaten-to-attack-israel) implies that the US and UK are supportive of DAESH, indirectly providing finances to them through Saudi Arabia. I'll pass on the details, but enough to say that there is little sources to support that answer.

So it sounds a lot like conspiration theories to me. I did flag it for low-quality and [downvoted](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2569/community-moderation). However the flag was declined with

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer.

I haven't been much active in flagging/moderating here until recently, but is it ok to leave such answers lying around?

Comment: The fact that that answer has 3 upvotes says a lot about P.SE

Answer (score 1):

Just like the decline message says, we don't delete answers for being wrong.  The mods aren't here to judge correctness, the community does that, and they do it with their votes.

What mods *will* delete is answers that don't even attempt to answer the question, so "thank you" comments, or off-topic rants or chit-chat will get deleted.

This is the way things are handled on Stack Overflow, and it should be the way that they are handled on most other SEs too.

Comment: Well, I disagree on different counts. For one, there are different types of flags for an answer. One is "not an answer", which you mention. *Another one* is "very low quality". So by SE standards both are considered valid grounds to delete an answer. Another point of notice is that due to the nature of the subjects, I don't think Politics.SE should follow strictly the same rules than SO. See Skeptics.SE, for example, where they have a rather strict exigence for questions and answers.

Comment: And that answer isn't just "wrong", it promotes highly speculative and unsupported claims, with the clear intent to promote an ideology. And I think we should be more strict with those as they give a bad image of the site. Note that this isn't the only concerned answer or question.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin that flag is called "**very** low quality" for a reason.  You use it on answers that are illegible garbage, or have other serious issues with them.  This answer comes nowhere close to that.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin and if these kinds of answers are consistently down-voted, then they will actually not be promoted.  If people are undermining your down-votes by up-voting those answers, then you'll just have to live with the fact that neither you, nor the moderators are the sole deciders of correctness on an SE site.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin If you think we have a quality problem, then you should instead make a meta thread to implore the community to have higher standards with their up and down votes